# c++ How do I print data from a struct to hListView in Windows Desktop Application

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, desktop-application

I am creating a GUI program where the user can set a future time and schedule a video or image to be played. The GUI consists of a datetime class, a "load video" button, and a listview of the schedule.

Relevant data types:

```
struct MultimediaFileInfo {
    std::wstring fileName;
    std::wstring filePath;
    SYSTEMTIME playDateTime;  // Scheduled time for playing the file
    // Add any other relevant info
};

std::vector<MultimediaFileInfo> multimediaFiles;
```

**THE QUESTION**

I have a listview generated with this function:

```
void InitializeListView(HWND hWnd)
{
    // Initialize the list view window; create it and set its style
    hListView = CreateWindowW(WC_LISTVIEW,
        L"",
        WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | WS_VISIBLE,
        10, 50, 600, 200, // Set the position and size appropriately
        hWnd,
        (HMENU)IDC_LISTVIEW,
        hInst,
        NULL);

    // Ensure that the common control DLL is loaded, and the listview is created.
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;
    icex.dwICC = ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

    // Set the extended listview style for full row select and grid lines.
    ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(hListView, LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_GRIDLINES);

    // Define columns for the listview. For example, three columns for file info.
    LVCOLUMN lvCol = { 0 };
    lvCol.mask = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_SUBITEM; // Mask specifying the format of the structure

    // Add columns to the ListView
    const int numColumns = 3;
    const wchar_t* columnTitles[numColumns] = { L"File Name", L"File Path", L"Play Time" };
    int columnWidths[numColumns] = { 100, 150, 150 };

    for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
        lvCol.pszText = (LPWSTR)columnTitles[i]; // Safe cast: LVCF_TEXT flag ensures text isn't modified
        lvCol.cx = columnWidths[i];
        ListView_InsertColumn(hListView, i, &lvCol);
    }
}
```

I can then press a "Load Video" button to search and select a video or image from my disk.

LoadMultimediaFile loads the media and incorporated datetime data from a DateTime Class, which the user can modify before pressing "Load Video".

The multimediaFileInfo  struct is then pushed back onto the vector of MultimediaFileInfo.

The data is then added to the listview for display.

```
void LoadMultimediaFile(HWND hListView, HWND hDateTimePicker) {
    // Open a dialog to let the user select a file
    OPENFILENAME ofn;       // common dialog box structure
    WCHAR szFile[260];      // buffer for file name
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    szFile[0] = '\0';

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hListView;
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
    ofn.lpstrFilter = L"Multimedia Files\0*.mp4;*.png\0All Files\0*.*\0";
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

    if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn) == TRUE) {
        // File was selected, now get the time from the DateTime Picker
        SYSTEMTIME selectedTime;

        DateTime_GetSystemtime(hDateTimePicker, &selectedTime); // Retrieves the date and time from the control

        WCHAR debugTimeStr[256];
        swprintf_s(debugTimeStr, 256, L"Selected Time: %04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",
            selectedTime.wYear, selectedTime.wMonth, selectedTime.wDay,
            selectedTime.wHour, selectedTime.wMinute, selectedTime.wSecond);
        OutputDebugString(debugTimeStr);

        // Now use 'selectedTime' and the selected file path for loading multimedia file
        AddMultimediaFile(hListView, szFile, selectedTime);
    }
    // Now, add the multimedia item to the ListView
    AddMultimediaItemToListView(hListView, multimediaFiles.size() - 1);
}



// Function to add a multimedia file to the system and update the list view
void AddMultimediaFile(HWND hListView, const std::wstring& filePath, const SYSTEMTIME& currentTime) {
    std::wstring fileName = filePath.substr(filePath.find_last_of(L"\\") + 1);

    // Debug: Print filename, filepath, and current time
    WCHAR debugMsg[256];
    swprintf_s(debugMsg, L"Adding Multimedia File:\nFilename: %s\nFilepath: %s\nCurrent Time: %04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",
        fileName.c_str(), filePath.c_str(),
        currentTime.wYear, currentTime.wMonth, currentTime.wDay,
        currentTime.wHour, currentTime.wMinute, currentTime.wSecond);
    OutputDebugString(debugMsg);

    MultimediaFileInfo newFileInfo = { fileName, filePath, currentTime };
    multimediaFiles.push_back(newFileInfo);


    AddMultimediaItemsToListView(hListView);
}




void AddMultimediaItemToListView(HWND hListView, size_t index) {
    // Ensure valid index
    if (index >= multimediaFiles.size()) {
        OutputDebugString(L"Index out of range in AddMultimediaItemToListView\n");
        return;
    }

    const MultimediaFileInfo& fileInfo = multimediaFiles[index];

    LVITEM lvItem = { 0 };
    lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
    lvItem.iItem = ListView_GetItemCount(hListView); // Get the next index

    // Prepare buffer for File Name
    WCHAR fileNameBuffer[MAX_PATH];
    wcsncpy_s(fileNameBuffer, fileInfo.fileName.c_str(), _TRUNCATE);
    lvItem.pszText = fileNameBuffer;
    lvItem.iSubItem = 0;  // Setting main item (Column 0)
    int itemIndex = ListView_InsertItem(hListView, &lvItem);

    // Ensure the item was inserted
    if (itemIndex == -1) {
        OutputDebugString(L"Failed to insert item into ListView\n");
        return;
    }

    // Set File Path in Column 1
    WCHAR filePathBuffer[MAX_PATH];
    wcsncpy_s(filePathBuffer, const_cast<LPWSTR>(multimediaFiles[index].filePath.c_str()), _TRUNCATE);
    ListView_SetItemText(hListView, itemIndex, 1, filePathBuffer);

    // Set Play Date and Time in Column 2
    WCHAR dateTimeBuffer[256];
    FormatDateTimeString(multimediaFiles[index].playDateTime, dateTimeBuffer, ARRAYSIZE(dateTimeBuffer));
    ListView_SetItemText(hListView, itemIndex, 2, dateTimeBuffer);

    WCHAR debugMsg[512];
    swprintf_s(debugMsg, L"Uploaded Multimedia File:\nFile Name: %s\nFile Path: %s\nPlay Date and Time: %s\n",
        fileNameBuffer, filePathBuffer, dateTimeBuffer);
    OutputDebugString(debugMsg);

    // Additional line to list out the data in multimediaFiles
    OutputDebugString(L"Listing all multimedia files:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < multimediaFiles.size(); ++i) {
        swprintf_s(debugMsg, 512, L"Index: %zu, File Name: %s, File Path: %s, Play Date and Time: %s\n",
            i, multimediaFiles[i].fileName.c_str(), multimediaFiles[i].filePath.c_str(),
            FormatSystemTime(multimediaFiles[i].playDateTime).c_str());  // Assuming FormatSystemTime is a function to format SYSTEMTIME to string
        OutputDebugString(debugMsg);
    }
}


void AddMultimediaItemsToListView(HWND hListView)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < multimediaFiles.size(); ++i)
    {
        AddMultimediaItemToListView(hListView, i);
    }

    InvalidateRect(hListView, NULL, TRUE);
    UpdateWindow(hListView);
}
```

**MY ISSUE:**
I cannot get the data to display from the MultimediaFileInfo struct to display onto the listView.

There is then a CheckandPlayVideo function that runs the media file at the appropriate time, which is not necessarily relevant here:

```
void CheckAndPlayMultimedia(HWND hWnd)
{
    SYSTEMTIME currentSystemTime;
    GetLocalTime(&currentSystemTime);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < multimediaFiles.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (CompareSystemTime(currentSystemTime, multimediaFiles[i].playDateTime))
        {
            // Construct the command to open the file based on the extension
            std::wstring command;

            // Check file extension (convert to lowercase for case-insensitive comparison)
            std::wstring extension = GetFileExtension(multimediaFiles[i].filePath);
            std::transform(extension.begin(), extension.end(), extension.begin(), towlower);

            if (extension == L"mp4")
            {
                EnableAutoRepeatForMP4();
                command = L"start \"\" /max wmplayer.exe /fullscreen \"" + multimediaFiles[i].filePath + L"\"";
            }
            else if (extension == L"png")
            {
                // For PNG files, open with the default image viewer
                command = L"start \"\" \"" + multimediaFiles[i].filePath + L"\"";
                RunCommand(command);  // Run the command to open the image file

                // Wait for 2 seconds (you can adjust the duration as needed)
                Sleep(5000);

                // Simulate pressing F11 using PowerShell
                SimulateKeyPress(0x7A);
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle other file types or show an error message
                MessageBox(hWnd, L"Unsupported file type.", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

                // Debug: Print unsupported file type
                OutputDebugString(GetFormattedDateTime(currentSystemTime).c_str());
                OutputDebugString(L" - Unsupported file type: ");
                OutputDebugString(extension.c_str());
                OutputDebugString(L"\n");

                continue;
            }

            // Debug: Print the command that will be executed
            OutputDebugString(GetFormattedDateTime(currentSystemTime).c_str());
            OutputDebugString(L" - Executing command: ");
            OutputDebugString(command.c_str());
            OutputDebugString(L"\n");

            // Launch the process
            int result = _wsystem(command.c_str());
            if (result == -1)
            {
                // An error occurred
                std::cerr << "Error launching multimedia player: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;

                // Debug: Print the error message
                OutputDebugString(GetFormattedDateTime(currentSystemTime).c_str());
                OutputDebugString(L" - Error launching multimedia player: ");
                OutputDebugString(std::to_wstring(errno).c_str());
                OutputDebugString(L"\n");
            }

            // Debug: Print the file being played
            OutputDebugString(GetFormattedDateTime(currentSystemTime).c_str());
            OutputDebugString(L" - Playing multimedia file: ");
            OutputDebugString(multimediaFiles[i].filePath.c_str());
            OutputDebugString(L"\n");

            // Remove the item from the list view and vector
            ListView_DeleteItem(hListView, i);
            multimediaFiles.erase(multimediaFiles.begin() + i);
            --i;  // Adjust the index as items are removed

            //////**** FLAG *****////
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it display? Are you sure the Listview takes its own copy of the string? If not your temporary `filePathBuffer` will cease to exist after the end of the function but the listview might be expecting the string data to be there. If that is the case you will need to store the text you want displayed in each item.

Comment: It currently displays nothing. Just the button, datetime and three header columns without any rows. I will look into pulling the data out of the buffer. the buffers do print successfully under the debugging output though

Comment: In an attempt to test this, i have moved all three buffers to global scope. the debug statement still prints out:

Uploaded Multimedia File:

File Name: 1025.mp4

File Path: C:\{PATH}\1025.mp4

Play Date and Time: 2024-01-04 15:52:59

but the data still doesnt add to listview


According to the documentation ListView_SetItemText automatically makes a copy of the text

Comment: Can you share a minimal example on GitHub so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: https://github.com/yfu7/ScreenScheduler

this is basically the full implementation

Comment: LoadMultimediaFile(hWnd, hDateTimePicker);  from definition, it requires hListView. And there are   multiMediaFiles and  multimediaFiles which puzzling.

Comment: multimediaFiles is the only one used here, i think multiMediaFiles was a previous artifact. I replaced hWnd with hListview, however i think this was from a previous edit I had made. Currently, when the list view is created, the parameters specify gridlines, whereas no gridlines actually appear. Could this be related to the information display issues I am encountering? Operationally, the app works as intended. The multimediaFiles just do not display in the list view.

Comment: Is there an error in my LoadMultimediaFile, AddMultimediaFile, or AddMultimediaFileToListView functions

Comment: The solutions seems to be to implement code under WM_NOTIFY

Comment: Add UpdateWindow(hListView); in WM_NOTIFY or remove WM_NOTIFY case, and `hListView `will display the items.
 By the way, you could convert your solution to an answer and accept it to close this thread.